# VB.NET WPF Selected Item in ListBox - Can't trigger selected item more than once

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I'm loading a UserControl, ucRegisterItem into a listbox called MainGrid.
The ucRegisterItem has a unique ID that I need to be able to retrieve when the item is clicked on inside of MainGrid.

With the code below, when instances of ucRegisterItem are loaded, I can click on each item once and retrieve the ID - but if i click on it again, nothing happens. I can add a new ucRegisterItem and get that ID, but again, just once.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the UC ucRegisterItem code:

```
    Public theOID As Integer
    Public Event OIDSelected(ByVal OID As Integer)

    Public Sub New(ByVal OID As Integer, ByVal Seat As Integer, ByVal Item As String, ByVal Qty As Double, ByVal Price As Double, ByVal SalesTax As Double, ByVal Total As Double, ByVal Optional Notes As String = "")

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        theOID = OID
        theSeat.Text = theOID 'Seat
        theProdName.Text = Item
        theQty.Text = Qty
        thePrice.Text = FormatCurrency(Price, 2)
        theTax.Text = FormatCurrency(SalesTax, 2)
        theTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(Total, 2)
        If Notes = "" Then
            ItemInfo.Children.Remove(ItemNotes)
        Else
            ActualNotes.Text = Notes
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub whatever_Selected(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles whatever.Selected
        RaiseEvent OIDSelected(theOID)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's where I'm loading it into my ListBox:

```
    Public Sub AddListItem(ByVal OID As Integer, ByVal Seat As Integer, ByVal Item As String, ByVal Qty As Double, ByVal Price As Double, ByVal SalesTax As Double, ByVal Total As Double, ByVal Optional Notes As String = "")
        Dim newItem As New ucRegisterItem(OID, Seat, Item, Qty, Price, SalesTax, Total, Notes)

        newItem.Name = "item" & OID


        MainGrid.Items.Add(newItem)
        MainGrid.SelectedIndex = MainGrid.Items.Count - 1
        MainGrid.ScrollIntoView(MainGrid.SelectedItem)

        AddHandler newItem.OIDSelected, AddressOf ShoutItOut
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShoutItOut(sender As Object)


        'Setting the value of this mug.
        selectedVal = CInt(sender)
        MsgBox("Value: " & sender.ToString)


    End Sub
```

I added the MsgBox to see what it would send.  I get the MsgBox to display once, but not on the second click or any click after on that specific item.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the expected behavior since when you click the selected item a second time it doesn't "Select" again so the event doesn't trigger.
You will have to either unselect the item programmaticaly or subscribe to a click event.

Comment: Thank's Ostas.  Articulous helped me over the phone while i was waiting for a response.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ostas has it right. You're subscribed to 'Selected' not 'Clicked' so change your event handler to a MouseUp or Click event.